# VBA Offset within Vlookup?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a Vlookup for a row which is just left of the Lookup_value.  I can't do a Table_array of "-1" (or -2) so I'm wondering if I can do an Offset(0, -1) within that line of code.

The line in question:

```
wCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],'[" & filename & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R8C4:R" & lastrow & "C5,-1,FALSE)"
```

The entire code block:

```
Range("$C$8:$C$" & lastrow).Select
    For Each wCell In Range("$C$8:$C$" & lastrow)
        wCell.Select
        If wCell.FormulaR1C1 = "" Then
            wCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],'[" & filename & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R8C4:R" & lastrow & "C5,-1,FALSE)"
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: If you're looking for information to the left of the reference, you should use Match-Index instead of VLookup. It's quicker and has the ability to look to the left or right of the information you reference. ([Link to more info](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-use-index-match-instead-vlookup))

Comment: @usfbs you should add that as an actual answer (provided you show a small example or show the OP how to do it with his VBA code)

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking to find information to the left of the reference point in excel, using a `Match-Index` lookup would be they way for you to go. Not only is this method able to look to the left or right of your reference, but it is also a faster process.

VLookup looks like this:

```
=VLookup([Value to find],[Where to find the value],[Column to return],[range lookup])
```

Where as using Match-Index looks like this:

```
=Index([Range to look in for return],Match([Value to find],[Range to look in for value],[Exact match or partial]))
```

So, while a bit more complicated to write, using the second method really increases the flexibility of what you can look up and where that information is.

Now, if you were to apply this method to your code, it should look something like this:

```
wCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Index([Range of Value to Find],Match(RC[1],'[" & filename & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R8C4:R" & lastrow & "C5, [0 for exact match]))"
```

(Just change out the bits I added in brackets for the information that they need, and that should address that problem your are running into)